# How can I do to change my SHELL from tcsh to bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I don't know how can I do that...  I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: How do you switched to tcsh? It is not used by default.

Comment: and `tcsh` is not even installed by default `:D`

Answer (score 6):

Run the following command in terminal:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

A log out and log back in is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do that with

```
sudo usermod -s <shell> <username>
```

shell : shell you want.

username: your username